# Wordpress site copy just redirects to live site

Tags: wordpress, config

I am having issues with my live site so I made a copy and migrated it manually. Using the standard SQL Query:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

But now when I enter the URL to the site it forwards to the actual live site. If you go to this text link you can see the behavior: http://www.testrachryracing2.com.php53-25.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/

Why is this happening? I don't see any redirects in the config file.

```
EDIT: Contents of .htaccess:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: perhaps there is a rule in your .htaccess ?

Comment: use this for replace url  http://github.com/interconnectit/search-replace-db

Comment: What about your wp-config.php file?

Comment: That was it. It was this line: define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '...');